# How are f64 types represented in 32 bit machines in Rust?

Tags: types, rust

I just realized we can use `f64` types even in a 32 bit machines with a bit of a performance trade-off. But, how is this achieved in Rust? Are two `f32` types bundled together as a makeshift `f64` type? Or something else going on behind the scenes?

Can someone explain how this is done without digging too deep into rust internals? (I'm still very new to Rust).

Comment: Simply checking [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) would tell you that combining two `f32` does not a `f64` make (2*23 != 52, you would be losing precision)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're represented in *exactly* the same way they're represented on a 64-bit machine; they're a hardware feature going back to the math co-processor for the 386, which was released somewhere around 1987.

Floats have *nothing* to do with the bitness of the machine.

The actual binary-level representation is documented exhaustively in other places, like the [Wikipedia page on the Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: thanks for clearing things up
Also, does Rust have an arbitrary precision type ?

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan Not in the standard library; I believe there's one in the `num` crate, and possibly others elsewhere.

Comment: What about instructions working with `f64` directly? Like multiplication, division or sin()... are those available on every x86 CPU for example?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Going back how far? The 80387 implemented full [IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), plus at least sin, cos, and tan.